# Imaginary value in Time Dilation Velocity number

Tags: special-relativity, time

Jack goes on a trip into space and returns. Jack's wrist watch tells him that 24 hours have passed for Jack, but for his friend who was on Earth the whole time, only 1 hour passed.

Using the Time Dilation formula below, to calculate what velocity does Jack need to travel, for this to be possible, I got the velocity as $23.98\cdot i \cdot c$ ( where 'i' is the square root of -1 ).

What would 'i' indicate in real life, in regards to velocity?

Yes, I am aware that there is no such thing as imaginary velocity, but still, I am hoping if someone might shed some new light on what the 'i' in my answer could mean or if it could represent some physical entity.

[image]

Comment: The time recorded on Jack's watch **must** be less that the time recorded on his friend's watch. It could be that Jack's watch records 1 hour while his friend's records 24 hours, but not the other way around. The $i$ in your calculation is telling you that the situation you describe is impossible.

Comment: @ John Rennie Aha! So are you saying that Jack can do something with his velocity and come back to an Earth where the year is 3135 AD but there is nothing he can do with his velocity such that he can come back to an Earth where the year is 1456 AD. Correct?

Comment: It isn't clear to me where you got those dates from. Suppose Jack leaves Earth at 00:00 on 1st Jan and travels for 24 hours as measured by Jack's watch. Then when he returns to Earth the time shown by the Earth clocks must be 00:00 on 2nd Jan or greater. That is, the time recorded by the Earth clocks in between Jack leaving and Jack returning must be equal to or greater than the 24 hours recorded on Jack's watch..

Comment: @ John Rennie Those dates were made to make my point clear. No, those dates have no relation to the original question.

Comment: @MarsSojourner: Accept this answer, then this question is 'closed'.

Answer (score 2):

Just to summarize @JohnRennie his comments, when an imaginary number pops up it is wrong. The situation is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is irrational, in that it assumes that an imaginary velocity has a meaning in real life. An imaginary velocity means that Jack either moves through an imaginary distance in a real time or that he moves through a real distance in an imaginary time, neither of which is a possibility in real life.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity scalar belongs to the real number set, so the situation you describe is not possible.